# Magento "Parcel Select" usps method not showing in front-end

Tags: magento, usps

i applied many usps method like First-Class Mail Parcel,Priority Mail 2-Day...... in my magento store all showing properly but "Parcel Select" method not displaying in front-end any idea????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contact to usps support system for this issue and they said  "I understand that Magento has Parcel Select as an available option for shipping, however you are not able to choose it as a shipping method. Please accept my apologies for the difficulties you are experiencing.

While Magento shows Parcel Select as an available option, it can only be used for customers that have a Bulk Mail Permit. If you have a Bulk Mail Permit, please contact Magento so that "Parcel Select" can be integrated into your website. If you do not have a Bulk Mail Permit, please contact your local Bulk Mail Entry Unit for more information on obtaining that permit."

So for "parcel select" method Bulk Mail Permit option available in client account.

Answer (score 1):

Check the criteria for that method, like country, zip etc. May be its not applicable for the rule set you have created.

Comment: thanx for reply...i checked everything right.i also checked in usps price calculator but parcel select method not showing there.You can check from here : http://postcalc.usps.com/MailServices.aspx?m=6&p=31&o=0&dz=48033&oz=08730&pob=0&MailingDate=8/22/2013&MailingTime=8:00%20AM